# How to migrate Entity Framework DB on publish via MsDeploy

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, msdeploy, entity-framework-migrations

For my current project i would prefer to update my database to the correct version on publish instead of first run via the App_Start.

It seems that there is support for manual upgrades via a commandline tool 'migrate.exe' which is supplied together with Entity Framework (5.0 rc2). But i can not find any information about how other people have combined this tool together with msdeploy to upgrade the database on publish instead of first run.

I have found the following page which explains how to use the migrate.exe tool:
http://blog.overridethis.com/blog/post/2012/03/13/Automating-EF-43x-Data-Migrations-in-your-Build.aspx

But this forces me to somehow 'know' the connectionstring information.

My optimal solution would be something like:

1. connectionstring is configured in setParameters.xml file for
   replacement on publish
2. on publish after publish of codebase
   migrate.exe gets called with correct connectionstring

It seems that what i search for is an 'entity framework MSDeploy provider'  (see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-released.aspx) but it seems that they abandoned that option some time ago

Comment: You can let your migration to generate SQL script for upgrade and use that script when publishing the web. I think it is currently not supported to run migrations during web deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Configure Visual Studio [Databases option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698#efcfmigrations) in the Publish Profile; or
2. Configure your project properties on [Package/Publish SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576376) Tab.

I didn't use any of them yet but I was researching because I'll have the exactly same scenario.